# Error in copying data fron one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy data from one workbook to another.

my source workbook, contains data with 722 rows. but the code is copying only 72 rows.

While I was debugging, in siiurcewkbk, I could see 722 rows being selected but then in destwkb its just 72 rows being pasted.

also, the column in my sourcewb is in AK and I want them to be pasted in column A of destwb.

Could anyone help me to rectify this issue.

```
Sub Extract()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim Val As Variant
Dim filename As String
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

CopyCol = Split("AK", ",")
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LCell = Activewindow.RangeSelection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address
LCC = Activewindow.RangeSelection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
lcr = Activewindow.RangeSelection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Set y = ThisWorkbook
    Dim path1, Path2
path1 = ThisWorkbook.Path
Path2 = path1 & "\Downloads"
Set x = Workbooks.Open(filename:=Path2 & "\Red.xlsx")

For Count = 0 To UBound(CopyCol)
  Set temp = Range(CopyCol(Count) & "1:" & CopyCol(Count) & lcr)
  If Count = 0 Then
    Set CopyRange = temp
  Else
    Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, temp)
  End If
Next

CopyRange.Copy
y.Sheets("All").Paste y.Sheets("All").Range("A4")
Application.CutCopyMode = False
x.Close
End Sub
```

anylead would be helpful.

Comment: You are gathering the last row into a var from one workbook then opening another workbook and using that var to determine how many rows to copy from whatever worksheet is active. Apples and oranges problem. Beyond everything else that is wrong, don't you simply want to open up a workbook from the downloads directory and copy one column of data into the original workbook?

Comment: @Jeeped  Yeah, I tried that earlier, and it dint work out. Can you suggest me a code in that case for doing so. The problem is  I am having my column in sourcewkb in column AK and I want it to be pasted in column A of destwkb. Could you suggest me a code in this case? I am new to vba may be it would be helpful for me

Comment: @JohnColeman I did the same thing last time and another expert suggested me to do it as an another question. and so I did it.

Comment: @JohnColeman since I could not figure out the problem, I posted it as an new questio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I commented out some lines that were doing nothing as far as I can see because I'm strict about code.  Also I added some Dim statements because I always write code with Option Explicit at the top of module, this is there to help the programmer as it traps hidden compile errors.

The solution to your problem is in the lines

```
    Dim rngLastCell As Excel.Range
    Set rngLastCell = Range(CopyCol(Count) & "65535").End(xlUp)
```

so what we're doing here is go to the last line of the sheet on row 65535 (I know later versions have more rows but this number is fine) and then we say End(xlUp) which logically means go up this column until you find some text which will be the bottom row of your block of data.

Just underneath I changed the syntax of the Range statement which is very flexible so one call Range with a string like Range("A1:B3") or one can call Range with two arguments each of them cells, so Range(Range("A1"),Range("B3")).

```
Option Explicit

Sub Extract()
    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim Val As Variant
    Dim filename As String
    Dim LastCell As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Dim CopyCol
    CopyCol = Split("AK", ",")

    '* LR is never used
    'LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    '* lc is never used
    'lc = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    '* LCell is never used
    'LCell = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address

    '* LCC is never used
    'LCC = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

    Dim lcr
    lcr = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    Set y = ThisWorkbook
    Dim path1, Path2
    path1 = ThisWorkbook.Path
    Path2 = path1 & "\Downloads"
    Set x = Workbooks.Open(filename:=Path2 & "\Red.xlsx")

    Dim Count As Long
    For Count = 0 To UBound(CopyCol)

        Dim rngLastCell As Excel.Range
        Set rngLastCell = Range(CopyCol(Count) & "65535").End(xlUp)

        Dim temp As Excel.Range
        'Set temp = Range(CopyCol(Count) & "1:" & CopyCol(Count) & lcr)
        Set temp = Range(CopyCol(Count) & "1", rngLastCell)
        If Count = 0 Then
            Dim CopyRange As Excel.Range
            Set CopyRange = temp
        Else
            Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, temp)
        End If
    Next

    CopyRange.Copy
    y.Sheets("All").Paste y.Sheets("All").Range("A4")
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    x.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked great :) but could you please comment the lines what they are doing ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are just coping one column of data from one worksheet to another column in another worksheet there is a lot easier way of doing it. 
Does the code below help?  Sorry if I've misunderstood your requirements ...

```
Sub Extract()
    Dim Path2 As String  '** path to the workbook you want to copy to ***
    Dim X As Workbook '*** WorkBook to copy from ****
    Dim Y As Workbook '** WorkBook to copy to

    Set X = ActiveWorkbook '** This workbook ****
    Path2 = "C:\test" '** path of book to copy to
    Set Y = Workbooks.Open(filename:=Path2 & "\Red.xlsx")
    X.Sheets("From").Range("A:A").Copy Destination:=Y.Sheets("ALL").Range("A1")
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Y.Save
    Y.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: As you have to be quick on this forum. I wrote the answer then had a phone conversation and by the time I'd clicked post. The thing had already been answered. I hope to Op is happy with their choices of answer...

Comment: Nice first Stack Overflow answer. I reformatted the code slightly since the first and last lines weren't being displayed inside the code box.

Comment: If I got that right, the OP "get" the data from the opened workbook and "paste" it to the Workbook with the code... so X and Y is switched... still a very good first answer.... +1

Comment: "As you have to be quick on this forum ... "  --  if you want to play that game. Personally, I prefer quality to quantity. Rep points are nice, but in my opinion the real reward for participating on Stack Overflow is when you deepen your knowledge by answering nontrivial questions, without worrying about whether or not your answer is first.

Comment: Totally agree John. You've made me spot a typo in my first comment. It was meant to say “Ah you have to be quick” not As.  The rest is correct, I wrote an answer then had a phone conversation (sneaking a cup of tea) and the page was awash with good answers.. I'm not chasing rep points as my local pub wont accept them in exchange for beer.

Answer (score 1):

`CopyCol = Split("AK", ",")` is `Array("AK")`... why?
`For Count = 0 To UBound(CopyCol) ... Next` runs from 0 to 0 (one cycle).

to put it in an shorter sub, I recommend something like this:

```
Sub Extract()

  Dim path1 As String
  path1 = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Downloads"

  Dim CopyCol As String
  CopyCol = "AK"

  With Workbooks.Open(filename:=path1 & "\Red.xlsx")

    With .ActiveSheet
      .Range(.Cells(1, CopyCol), .Cells(.Rows.Count, CopyCol).End(xlUp)).Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("All").Range("A4")
    End With

  .Close
  End With

End Sub
```